# Cordova deprecated when using Ionic Framework for SocialSharing ng-Cordova plugin

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova

When I run my app in xcode, it advises me there are 2 errors:

```
"dataFromBase64String:base64content" is deprecated
suggests added cdv to create "cdv_dataFromBase64String:base64content"
```

The error in the browser console is clearly:

```
Cannot read property 'socialsharing' of undefined.
```

Not sure if this is a fix I can go in and manually do somehow? Or if I need to abandon this plugin.

Direction or advise would be greatly appreciated. Or alternative plugins that work natively to use with Ionic.